# OpenCPU admin opencpu.demo

Tags: r, opencpu

I am recieveing an error when I run the

admin app on my OpenCPU Server
    Error Message : 
    Not Found

```
The requested URL /Radmin/call/opencpu.demo/install.opencpu/json was not found on this server.
```

I have the R folder of the opencpu repo and the package installed yet I dont know where the install.opencpu function file is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you found the `/Radmin/` url, but that feature never made it into opencpu. Try to stick with the stuff from the manual page: www.opencpu.org.